# Spark scala full join outputs null on joining column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, outer-join

I am trying to combine 2 dataframes with the same column names to create a larger new dataframe, keeping all data. I use coalesce to replace values from one dataframe if the same id exists.

The join and coalesce turns out fine, but the joining column ("id") results in `null` value when the id exist. Not sure why:

Example:

```
val tmp = Seq(
  (1,"A"),
  (2,"B"),
  (3,"A"),
  (4,"A")
).toDF("id","label")


val tmp2 = Seq(
  (1,"B"),
  (2,"B"),
  (3,"B"),
  (5, "A")
).toDF("id","label")
```

code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// replace values in tmp(label) with tmp2(label) if both have same id.
val tmp3 = tmp.join(tmp2, tmp("id") === tmp2("id"), "fullouter")
           .select(tmp("id"), coalesce(tmp2("label"), tmp("label")))

output:
+----+----------------------+
|  id|coalesce(label, label)|
+----+----------------------+
|null|                     A|
|   1|                     B|
|   2|                     B|
|   3|                     B|
|   4|                     A|
+----+----------------------+
```

Wanted:

```
output:
+----+----------------------+
|  id|coalesce(label, label)|
+----+----------------------+
|   5|                     A|
|   1|                     B|
|   2|                     B|
|   3|                     B|
|   4|                     A|
+----+----------------------+
```

changing the join to `"full"` our `"outer"` has the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing a full outer join, so it will combine all the rows from both tables.

Since you are using the `id` from `tmp` as result id, when there is a row in `tmp2` which is absent in `tmp` it can't take a valid value so that's null

To get your expected output you can use another `coalesce` in the first column, the same as you are doing in the second

```
val tmp3 = tmp.join(tmp2, tmp("id") === tmp2("id"), "fullouter")
.select(coalesce(tmp("id"), tmp2("id")), coalesce(tmp2("label"), tmp("label")))
+----------------+----------------------+
|coalesce(id, id)|coalesce(label, label)|
+----------------+----------------------+
|               1|                     B|
|               3|                     B|
|               5|                     A|
|               4|                     A|
|               2|                     B|
+----------------+----------------------+
```